# How to display a mat-error message without a form control, but with matInput?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code in my `Material table`:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="columnDef">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Column heading</th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
       <mat-form-field>
             <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.myField">
             <mat-error *ngIf="row.myField > 0"> My error message </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

The thing is that mat-form-field is not a `FormControl`, but it would be nice if `mat-error` would somehow validate this input and display the error message.

Can someone tell me if it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a span attribute with custom style:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.myField">
      <span *ngIf="row.myField > 0"
             class="error">My error message
      </span>
</mat-form-field>
```

component.css (this is just an example)

```
.error {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking if there's a possibility to use mat-error instead.

Answer (score 22):

While `<mat-error>` is tied to an error condition of the `formControl`, `<mat-hint>` is not.

You can try this hack:

```html
<mat-form-field [class.mat-form-field-invalid]="hasError">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="some.model">
  <mat-hint class="mat-error" *ngIf="hasError">Error Message</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Yes I can see the text. But lost the fly-in animaiton.

Comment: This is also work but the solution is not the proper standard

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, when using mat-error as designed the error is not taking vertical space when is shown.  But hint does take space. As a result, if you have two fields shown vertically the hint increases vertical distance between fields.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct that `mat-form-field` is not a form control, but `matInput` is.  You just need to wrap the input in a form and specify the `name` for the form control when you are using `ngModel` binding.  You can use the built in `min` validator on a number type input to do the check for you, then Angular Material will integrate with the FormsModule to hide/show the error as appropriate.  The code below should work:

```html
<form>
    <table mat-table>
        ...

        <ng-container matColumnDef="columnDef">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Column heading</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="row.myField" [min]="0" [name]="'myField'+row.id">
                    <mat-error>My error message</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

Note that you need to use a unique row id in the `name` to make sure that each row gets a unique control in the NgForm.  If you don't have a unique column to use you can create a form inside the `td` element.

Comment: Can we use matInput in select field also?

Answer (score 2):

I think following code will give good solution. I have done the auto validation trigger when the user navigated to the component.

Below example implemented for required validation, based on your requirement change the validator

```html
     <mat-form-field>
             <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.myField" #sampleField="ngModel" required>
             <mat-error *ngIf="sampleField.invalid && (sampleField.errors && sampleField.errors['required'])"> My error message </mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>
```

If you don't want to auto trigger the validation then can skip the below ts statements

```js
//in ts
     @ViewChild('sampleField', { static: false }) 
     set input(element: NgModel) {
       if(element) {
         element.control.markAllAsTouched()
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```html
<mat-form-field
  appearance="fill"
  class="mat-input"
  [ngClass]="{ 'mat-form-field-invalid': !!errorMessage }"
  [floatLabel]="'always'"
>
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="object[valueProperty]"
    (focusout)="onFocusLost()"
  />
  <span class="error" *ngIf="!!errorMessage"> {{ errorMessage }}</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
  onFocusLost() {
    setTimeout(this.validate, 200);
  }
  
  validate=()=> {
    this.errorMessage = this.validator.ValidationMessage(text);
  }
```

```css
.error {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a reference to the `<mat-chip-list>` element you can manually set it's `errorState` property

```
@ViewChild('chipList') chipList;

setErrorState(): void {
  this.chipList.errorState = this.dataList.length >= 0;
}
```

Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matchiplist-with-error-message?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.ts

Answer (score -1):

`<mat-error *ngIf="row.myField.length > 0"> My error message </mat-error>`

You are missing the `.length` of your `row.myField > 0`

Comment: I don't need to check the length on this one. It's not an array, it's just an input value. Your solution doesn't work.

Comment: You can check the length on the `input` too, and for input you can just do *ngIf="row.myField" you don't need the `>` operator at all then.

Comment: @user7435747 I think there is something wrong with your `row.myField` did you try `<mat-error *ngIf="true"> My error message </mat-error>` just to see if that will work ?